# How i can look full pandas.dataframe columns in pycharm intstead "..."?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I just need to know how I can see all my frame columns in output:

[image: frame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the option_context, with one or more options:**

Try this just right after specifying dataframe:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', None): 
    print(df)
```